# D'où vient précisément « saperlipopette » ?

Tags: expressions, étymologie, jurons

Comme tout le monde je pense vous avez déjà dû entendre quelqu'un s'exprimer en disant « Saperlipopette ! », même si ce n'est (il me semble) plus très courant aujourd'hui (je me souviens encore de vieux dessins animés qui employaient cette expression).

Je serais curieux de connaître l'origine de cette expression, en cherchant sur google j'ai trouvé [ici](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/saperlipopette) qu'il semblerait que cela soit utilisé depuis 1863 comme une évolution de *saperlotte*. Pourquoi 1863 ? Et pourquoi ne pas avoir gardé *saperlotte* ? Je n'ai pas réussi à trouver plus d'infos sur le sujet, si vous avez des pistes je suis preneur, merci d'avance !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Le journal du **Courrier du Vaugelas**, en 1880, semble s'être beaucoup intéressé à cette question. Il faudrait d'ailleurs poser une nouvelle question pour savoir pourquoi diable le *Courrier du Vaugelas* a voulu expliquer à ses lecteurs l'origine du mot *saperlipopette* car là, je n'en sais rien.

Ici, [l'avis d'un professeur au lycée de Pontivy](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k58331587/f2.image.r=saperlipopette.langFR) sur cette très importante question, le 2 février 1880.

Là, le journal, dans sa 9ème année, [précise une opinion](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5833152r/f1.image.r=saperlipopette.langFR) exprimée sur le mot *saperlipopette* dans sa 5ème année.

Et maintenant, il s'agirait de savoir si tout cela est vrai !

Résumé de ces liens : **saperlipopette** viendrait de *saperlotte*, qui vient du flamand *saperloot*, de l'allemand *sapperlot*, composé de *sapper* (sacré, ou damné, maudit) et *lot* (hasard, sort).

À noter que ce journal ne semble pas connaître une origine par Rimbaud ?

Comment: D'abord la première publication de Rimbaud date de 1866 et il n'était certainement pas encore très connu en 1870, et surement pas sa prose d'écolier, même pas par les lecteurs d'une revue spécialisée en langue française comme le Courrier de Vaugelas.
Par ailleurs si l'apparition de *saperlipopette* dans un écrit date de 1864 il est possible que Rimbaud ne fasse que fixer à l'écrit un mot déjà utilisé dans la langue parlée.

Answer (score 11):

*Saperlipopette* vient de *sacrer* (->*jurer*). Employé pour la première fois par Rimbaud en 1864 dans [*Proses et vers de collège*](http://visualiseur.bnf.fr/CadresFenetre?O=NUMM-101484&M=notice) (il avait 10 ans).

> Ah! saperlipotte de saperlipopette! sapristi! moi je serai rentier; il
>   ne fait pas si bon de s'user les culottes sur les bancs,
>   saperlipopettouille!

Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, qui fait référence à Rimbaud, indique que c'est la resuffixation de *saperlotte*, *saprelotte*, altération de *sacrelotte* (1750), altération de *sacrer*.

En suivant *sacrer* dans  le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* j'ai appris qu'un *sacre*  n.m.(1549) est une :

> « formule de juron, régional mais courant dans l'usage général au
>   Canada (1864, Clapin). Les sacres sont une partie très spécifique du
>   vocabulaire franco-canadien et utilisent quantité de mots empruntés au
>   culte (*hostie, tabernacle*) ou de noms propres sacrés (notamment
>   *Christ*).

Et le dictionnaire cite : sacrebleu (*par la sacre bleu* déformation de *par la sacre Dieu*), sacrédié, sacristi, sapristi, saprédié, saguernon. Certains sont tombés dans l'oubli de nos jours, à moins qu'au Canada ? ...

Comment: Saperlipopette comme "sacre" Canadien? C'est bien un des trucs les plus tordus que j'ai jamais lus. Si c'est le cas, il était tombé d'aplomb dans l'oubli dès le milieu du vingtième siècle. Notons qu'Hergé place le mot dans la bouche de Tintin à douze occasions (*Dicionnaires des Noms Propres de Tintin*, 1992, p. 234), ce n'est donc clairement pas une expression spécifique au Canada.

Comment: @Circeus « Sacrer » comme synonyme de « jurer » n'est guère utilisé de nos jours qu'au Canada, mais ce ne fut pas toujours le cas.

Comment: @Laure je me suis un peu emberlificoté en lisant les définitions et en particulier le "régional mais courant dans l'usage général au Canada". Dsl.

Comment: Soit dit en passant, quant au "à moins qu'au Canada...?", *sacristi* est un sacre en usage au Québec, mais vraisemblablement c'est le mot [*sacristie*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacristie) (de même que les autres sacres dérivent directement de termes liés au service religieux) et non un ["minced oath"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath) pour *sacredieu*.

Comment: Habitant à proximité de la frontière belge (mais coté français), il me semble que c'est (ou disons *a été*) plus employé en Belgique qu'en France. A vérifier cependant.

Answer (score 2):

Une formule d'argot hébraïque comme abracadabra...
*Sapere*, infinitif du verbe *Lessapere* pour *sipour*, *sefer*, *sefira*. En français, *conter*, *narrer*.
Li, moi…
Popette, historiette…
  Sens: Tu me racontes des blagues…