# Exploration du patrimoine du juron religieux en littérature française : éléments, chronologie, fonction ?

Tags: littérature, jurons

Il y a [quelques questions](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jurons) sur les *jurons*, individuellement; il y en a [une](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/419) au sujet des *sacres* au Québec; sur *Wikipédia*, on a un [article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacres_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois) complet sur les sacres au Québec. En ce qui a trait au [*juron religieux*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacres_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois) en littérature française, on a très peu d'information. J'ai appris que le [capitaine Haddock](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocabulaire_du_capitaine_Haddock) n'a jamais prononcé *sacrebleu* de sa vie, mais encore ?

---

De quels mots se compose généralement le **patrimoine historique du juron religieux en France** ? A-t-on une idée de la chronologie de l'attestation des emplois en littérature universelle ? Quels sont généralement les contextes d'emploi des jurons; les auteurs s'autorisent-ils eux-mêmes les jurons où les mettent-ils dans la bouche de leur personnages; le cas échéant est-ce toujours vulgaire; y a-t-il un profil type de celui/celle qui jure en littérature française ? Le juron français a-t-il toujours la même fonction dans l'histoire et quel est l'impact de la sémantique des éléments constituants sur la fonction, si impact il y a ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

À défaut d'avoir l'expertise pour faire une recherche lexicographique avec [datation](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14378), on peut faire un exercice de *présentation* de l'information. Voici un tri<sup>1</sup> de quelques éléments des sections d'étymologie au *TLFi* en ce qui a trait au patrimoine du juron religieux français. La sélection est basée, arbitrairement, sur les mots *sacre* — *sang* — *nom* — *Dieu*, essentiellement, avec certains euphémismes, altérations ou curiosités; incluant les liens vers les vedettes, et *tous* les contextes en littérature (universelle) des sections *étymologie* pour les entrées produites :

> **1174-77** [*par Dieu*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pardieu) ([*Le Roman de Renart*](http://gallicalabs.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6553768q/f271.image.r=%22par%20dieu%22), éd. M. Roques, br. III, 4054)
>   **1179** [*por le cuer bieu*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/corbleu) ([*Renart*](http://gallicalabs.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k65534285/f297.image.r=bieu), éd. M. Roques, 563)
>   **1220** *par le cuer bieu* (G. de Coincy, II [*Miracles*](http://gallicalabs.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54475281/f149.item.r=bieu) 13, 698)
>   **1205-50** *por le cuer Dieu* ([*Renart*](https://books.google.com/books?id=EHtm6MskHIUC&lpg=RA1-PA230&ots=Vi1ujdqf7E&dq=%22cuer%20Dieu%22%20renart&pg=RA1-PA230#v=onepage&q=%22cuer%20Dieu%22%20renart&f=false), 13604)
>   **----** *li cors Dieu le maudie* ([*Moniage Guillaume*](https://archive.org/stream/lesdeuxrdacti01moni#page/8/mode/2up/search/maudie), Première rédaction, 196, éd. W. Cloetta, t. 1, p. 9)
>   **1368** *par le [sang](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sang) de [Dieu](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dieu)* (par le [sambuy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/sambuy), Arch. J.J. 99, pièce 179 ds Gdf.)
>   **1377** [*par le sanc Dieu*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/palsambleu) (d'apr. [FEW t.11, p.177b](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/79767))
>   **1402** [*par le sanc bieu*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/palsambleu) (Arch. Nord B 11513, fol. 4 vods IGLF; par ex. [Pathelin](https://books.google.com/books?id=VvKtXU63eF0C&lpg=PA258&dq=%22par%20le%20sanc%20bieu%22&pg=PA224#v=onepage&q=%22par%20le%20sanc%20bieu%22&f=false), 1460)
>   **1534** *le [corps](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/corps) Dieu* (Rabelais, [*Gargantua*](http://xtf.bvh.univ-tours.fr/xtf/view?docId=tei/B751131011_Y2_2126/B751131011_Y2_2126_tei.xml;chunk.id=n27;toc.depth=1;toc.id=;brand=default;query=corps%20Dieu#1), XXVII, éd. Marty-Laveaux, t. 1, p. 105)
>   **1546** *corbieu* (Rabelais, [*Tiers Livre*](http://xtf.bvh.univ-tours.fr/xtf/view?docId=tei/B372616101_3537/B372616101_3537_tei.xml;chunk.id=n10;toc.depth=1;toc.id=;brand=default;query=corbieu#1), VII, t. 2, p. 43)
>   **1549** *et [sacre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sacre/2) du Gouvernement* ([*Agréable réc. ds Ch. de mazarin.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=1QW3Qx2HALcC&lpg=PR7&ots=d0PDpjkyYu&dq=Agr%C3%A9able%20r%C3%A9cit%20in%20Choix%20de%20mazarinades&pg=PA16#v=snippet&q=%22sacre%20du%22&f=false), I, 16 ds [Quem. DDL t. 19](https://books.google.com/books?ei=M96hVf2rPIWrNvamg9AH&id=sOUcAQAAIAAJ&dq=mat%C3%A9riaux%20lexicographiques%20quemada%20%22volume%2018%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=sacre))
>   **1552** *[Sacre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sacre/2) Dieu* (Rabelais, [*Quart Livre*](http://visualiseur.bnf.fr/CadresFenetre?O=NUMM-27833&I=247&M=tdm), chap. 47, éd. R. Marichal, p. 268), attest. isolée
>   **1564** [*cor dieu*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cordieu) (Rabelais, [*Cinquième Livre*](http://xtf.bvh.univ-tours.fr/xtf/view?query=%22cor%20dieu%22&docId=tei%2FB751131011_RES_Y2_2169%2FB751131011_RES_Y2_2169_tei.xml&chunk.id=n16), XIII, t. 3, p. 53)
>   **1577** [*parbieu*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parbleu) (R. Belleau, [*Reconnue*](http://gallicalabs.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k27687m/f298.image.r=parbieu), V, 1 ds OEuvres, II, 428 ds IGLF)
>   **1642** *par la [sacre-bleu](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sacrebleu)* (G. Brunet, [*Le Nouv. siècle de Louis XIV*](http://visualiseur.bnf.fr/CadresFenetre?O=NUMM-27833&I=247&M=tdm), 8 ds [Quem. DDL t. 19](https://books.google.com/books?ei=M96hVf2rPIWrNvamg9AH&id=sOUcAQAAIAAJ&dq=mat%C3%A9riaux%20lexicographiques%20quemada%20%22volume%2018%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=sacre%20bleu))
>   **1643** [*parbleu*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parbleu) (Scarron, [Recueil de quelques vers burle.](http://gallicalabs.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k72450j/f27.image.r=scarron%20burlesques), 15 ds Richardson, p.199)
>   **1664** *par la [morbleu](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/morbleu)* (Molière, [*Princesse d'Elide*](http://gallicalabs.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6180035v/f13.image.r=morbleu), 1erintermède, scène 2)
>   **1665** *morbleu* (Id., [*Dom Juan*](http://gallicalabs.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5817836r/f80.image.r=morbleu), III, 1)
>   **1665** [*dame*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dame) (Id., [*Dom Juan*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5817836r/f79.item.r=dame), III, 1, p. 58)
>  
>   **1668** *[corbleu](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/corbleu)* (Molière, [*Georges Dandin*](http://gallicalabs.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k61800279/f5.image.r=corbleu), I, 4)
>  
>   **1690** *tredame* (comme *dame*, abréviation basée sur [*par Notre-Dame*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/notre-dame)/damedieu, la Vierge Marie)
>   **1691** [*palsambleu*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/palsambleu) (Dancourt, [*La Folle Enchère*](https://books.google.com/books?id=klpeAAAAcAAJ&dq=Dancourt%20%22La%20Folle%20Ench%C3%A8re%22%20palsambleu&pg=PA174#v=onepage&q=palsambleu&f=false), 196 ds IGLF)
>   **1745** [*sacrebleu*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sacrebleu) (Godard d'Aucour, [*L'Académie militaire*](https://books.google.com/books?id=6vdaAAAAQAAJ&vq=sacrebleu&pg=PA263#v=snippet&q=sacrebleu&f=false), I, 49, ds [Quem. DDL t. 17](https://books.google.com/books?ei=M96hVf2rPIWrNvamg9AH&id=sOUcAQAAIAAJ&dq=mat%C3%A9riaux%20lexicographiques%20quemada%20%22volume%2018%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=sacrebleu)).
>   **1750** [*sacrelote*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sacrelotte) ([Vadé?] *Le Paquet de mouchoirs*)
>   **1750** *[sacre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sacre/2) non pas d'un chien* (J.-J. Vadé, [*Le Paquet de mouchoirs*](https://books.google.com/books?id=qK9aAAAAcAAJ&dq=%22Le%20Paquet%20de%20mouchoirs%22%20vad%C3%A9&pg=PA41#v=onepage&q=sacre&f=false), p. 41)
>   **(1752)** *cordieu* ([Trévoux](https://books.google.com/books?ei=DFOiVe2OAsWjNqqEkIAK&id=ELE-AQAAMAAJ&dq=%22journal%20de%20trevoux%22%20cordieu&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=cordieux), err.?)
>   **1757** *par la [sacredié](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sacredi%C3%A9)!* ([aussi](https://books.google.com/books?id=YRFbAAAAQAAJ&dq=inauthor%3A%22Jean%20Joseph%20Vad%C3%A9%22&pg=PA79#v=onepage&q=sacre&f=false)) (J.-J. Vadé, [*Œuvres posth.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-EcGAAAAQAAJ&dq=inauthor%3A%22Jean%20Joseph%20Vad%C3%A9%22%20%22par%20la%20sacredi%C3%A9%22&pg=PA191#v=onepage&q=inauthor:%22Jean%20Joseph%20Vad%C3%A9%22%20%22par%20la%20sacredi%C3%A9%22&f=false), p. 254) 
>   **1789** *[sacre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sacre/2)-nom d'un cœur* ([*Compl. des poiss. de Par. à MM. les élect.*](http://gallicalabs.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k40343w/f7.image.r=coeur.zoom), p. 4 ds [Quem. DDL t. 19](https://books.google.com/books?ei=M96hVf2rPIWrNvamg9AH&id=sOUcAQAAIAAJ&dq=mat%C3%A9riaux%20lexicographiques%20quemada%20%22volume%2018%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=sacr%C3%A9%20nom))
>   **1790** *saguernon*
>   **1790** *sacré nom d'une [pipe](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pipe)*
>   **1790** [*sacristie*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sacristi) ([*Le Père Duchesne*](https://books.google.com/books?ei=NeqhVffqK8Xk-QHo9JfwDA&id=sGMrAAAAIAAJ&dq=Le%20P%C3%A8re%20Duchesne%20h%C3%A9bert&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=sacr), p. 2 ds Quem. DDL t. 32: *ah! Sacr...istie...*)
>   **1805** (1790 *DHLF/Rey*) *[nom](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nom) de [Dieu](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dieu)!* (Courier, [*Lettres Fr. et Ital.*](http://gallicalabs.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k57191960/f105.image.r=%22nom%20de%20dieu%22), p.699)
>   **1808** *sacristie* (Hautel, s.v. [sacrebleu!](https://books.google.com/books?id=dqIFAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA327&focus=viewport&vq=sacrebleu&hl=fr))
>   **1809** [*saperlotte*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/saperlotte) (Désaugiers et Gentil, [*M. La Gobe*](https://books.google.com/books?id=SXxLAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PA10&ots=pS0dLitnjD&dq=D%C3%A9saugiers%20et%20Gentil%20%22M.%20La%20Gobe%22&pg=PA12#v=onepage&q=saperlotte&f=false), p. 12 ds [Quem. DDL t. 18](https://books.google.com/books?ei=M96hVf2rPIWrNvamg9AH&id=sOUcAQAAIAAJ&dq=mat%C3%A9riaux%20lexicographiques%20quemada%20%22volume%2018%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=saperlotte))
>   **1827** [*sacristi!*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sacristi) (Cavé et Dittmer, [*Les Soirées de Neuilly*](https://books.google.com/books?id=V9c5AAAAcAAJ&dq=Les%20Soir%C3%A9es%20de%20Neuilly&pg=PA361#v=onepage&q=sacristi&f=false), I, p. 360-1 ds Quem. DDL t. 15).
>   **1828-29** [*sacredieu*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sacredieu) (Vidocq, [*Mémoires*](https://books.google.com/books?id=CHdKAAAAMAAJ&dq=vidocq%20m%C3%A9moires&pg=PA160#v=onepage&q=sacredieu&f=false), t. 3, p. 160)
>   **1834** (1799 *DHLF/Rey*) *nom d'un petit [bonhomme](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bonhomme) !* (Balzac, [*Eugénie Grandet*](http://gallicalabs.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5482101j/f244.image.r=%22nom%20d'un%20petit%20bonhomme%22), 1834, p. 190)
>   **1835** [*saquerlotte*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/saperlotte) (Balzac, [*Chabert*](https://books.google.com/books?id=T3sTchpbdg0C&dq=Chabert%20balzac&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q=saquerlotte&f=false), p. 10)
>   **1835** [*sapristi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sapristi) (Balzac, [*Goriot*](https://books.google.com/books?id=LvILAAAAIAAJ&dq=editions%3AZIBzHkk8SDQC&pg=PA249#v=onepage&q=sapristi&f=false), p. 253). Corruption de sacristi*.
>   **----** [*sapristoche*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sapristoche)
>   **1835-1900** [*pristi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pristi)
>   **1840** *nom de nom*
>   **1843** *nom d'un nom*
>   **1851** [*saprelotte*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/saperlotte) (Labiche, [*Chapeau paille Ital.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=KFNUAAAAcAAJ&dq=Chapeau%20paille%20Italie&pg=PA73#v=onepage&q=saper&f=false), V, 9, p. 125)
>   **1864** [*saperlipopette*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/saperlipopette) (Rimbaud, [*Proses et vers de collège*](http://visualiseur.bnf.fr/CadresFenetre?O=NUMM-101484&M=notice), I ds Œuvres compl., Pléiade, 1963, p. 5)
>   **1864** *saperlipotte/saperlipopettouille/saperlipouille/saperpouillotte* (*Ibid.*, voir aussi [Q&A](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/2571))
>   **1866** [*cristi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sacristi)
>   **1869** nom d'un [chien](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chien) (*ventre-non d'un*, 1744, DHLF/Rey)
>   **----** 
>   [*crébleu*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cr%C3%A9bleu) (sacrebleu) Maupassant ([*Hist. vraie*](http://gallicalabs.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k1031357/f300.image.r=cr%C3%A9bleu), 1882)
>  *crebleu*
>   Courteline, ([*Train 8 h 47*](http://gallicalabs.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k66300g/f181.image.r=cr%C3%A9bleu), 1888)
>  *crédieu* (sacredieu) Bernanos ([*Imposture*](https://books.google.com/books?id=q1AnAAAAMAAJ&dq=editions%3AxJgU3q4KdtEC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=cr%C3%A9dieu), 1927)
>  *crénom* (1847, *DHLF/Rey*) (sacré nom de Dieu) Montherland ([*Lépreuses*](https://books.google.com/books?ei=bfyhVZqyNsnv-QGIyZj4DQ&id=7_pKAQAAIAAJ&dq=Montherland%20L%C3%A9preuses&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=cr%C3%A9nom), 1939)
>  *crédié* Bernanos ([*Ouine*](https://books.google.com/books?id=UyNBAQAAIAAJ&q=ouine%20bernanos%20%22cr%C3%A9di%C3%A9%22&dq=ouine%20bernanos%20%22cr%C3%A9di%C3%A9%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FzmiVanAAsXegwT_955I&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ), 1946)
>
> ---
>
> *Varia*
>
> **1250** [*par le sacrement*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sacrement) (orig. *saccrament*, 980, *DHLF/Rey*) ([*Doon de Mayence*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9DrWHPygD8AC&dq=Doon%20de%20Mayence&pg=PA189#v=onepage&q=sacrement&f=false), éd. Gues. 6247)
>   **(1900-)** *sacrement* (La Varende, [*Roi d'Écosse*](https://books.google.com/books?id=rtk9AAAAIAAJ&dq=editions%3AHe-VEv2yFcgC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22sacrements%22), 1941; M. Tremblay [*À toi, pour toujours...*](https://books.google.com/books?id=vu4uAAAAIAAJ&dq=editions%3AhZiiaLIaYkgC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22on%20ira%20pas%22), 1971)
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé*, TLFi, aux sections
>   *étymologie* pour toutes les vedettes suivant les dates, avec quelques ajouts provenant du *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*,
>   sous dir. Alain Rey, ed. *Le Robert* ]

Cette présentation n'autorise aucune conclusion; on observe certaines transformations, l'altération par euphémisme, le changement de préfixe/suffixe, qui éloignent lentement du sens distinct des mots; on note que le juron religieux est représenté dans la littérature et que les mots sélectionnés sont prolifiques; on note que les emplois *nom de* + substantif sont relativement récents. Il faut s'approprier les contextes et se faire une idée des emplois au delà des [généralités](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/juron). Pour avoir une brève idée de l'usage au corpus de *Google*, voir ce [ngram (variété)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nom+de+dieu%2Csacre+Dieu%2Csacrebleu%2Csacredi%C3%A9%2Csacristi%2Csaperlotte%2Csaperlipopette%2Ccrebleu%2Ccr%C3%A9di%C3%A9%2Ccr%C3%A9nom%2Csapristi&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnom%20de%20dieu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csacre%20Dieu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csacrebleu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csacredi%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csacristi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csaperlotte%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csaperlipopette%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrebleu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccr%C3%A9di%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccr%C3%A9nom%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csapristi%3B%2Cc0), ce [ngram (parbleu + jurons modernes)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=parbleu%2Cnom%20de%20dieu%2Csacrebleu%2Csacristi%2Csaperlotte%2Csaperlipopette%2Ccrebleu%2Cbordel%2Cputain%2Cmerde&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cparbleu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnom%20de%20dieu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csacrebleu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csacristi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csaperlotte%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csaperlipopette%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrebleu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbordel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cputain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmerde%3B%2Cc0), et ce [ngram (nom de + subst.)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nom%20de%20*_NOUN&year_start=1650&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cnom%20de%20*_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnom%20de%20l%27_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnom%20de%20Dieu_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnom%20de%20M._NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnom%20de%20famille_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnom%20de%20J%C3%A9sus_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnom%20de%20Jean_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnom%20de%20Charles_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnom%20de%20Louis_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnom%20de%20S._NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnom%20de%20Saint_NOUN%3B%2Cc0).

---

<sub>1. Évidemment, la liste n'a pas vocation à étayer l'apparition des jurons à l'oral, ni même les premiers emplois à l'écrit, au-delà de ce que font les sources choisies (TLFi sections ety., DHLF/Rey). La liste présente des exemples représentatifs des certaines époques avec des auteurs et des œuvres davantage connus. Il s'agit d'une exploration. Il y a d'autres avertissements à formuler: je fais miens les [commentaires](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2571/do%C3%B9-vient-pr%C3%A9cis%C3%A9ment-saperlipopette#comment4322_2572) qu'on a faits ici sur Rimbaud quand on remarque qu'il a *10 ans* lorsqu'il utilise *saperlipopette* et que certains choix peuvent refléter l'usage du temps, par exemple à l'oral; certainement un auteur de la trempe de celui-ci peut inventer des mots; d'autre part le mots ne tombent pas du ciel et ils s'inscrivent justement dans un contexte historique et/ou qui relève d'un choix particulier qu'un auteur fait (registre, etc.). La liste reflète cette réalité et présente quelques jalons pour fins de réflexion sur les questions posées.</sub>