# « Impeach the mf » : ...le fils de pute ? (NSFW)

Tags: sens, traduction, anglais, argot, grossieretes

Despite having no account on such a network, I've become aware of a hashtag containing a vulgar slang term: "impeachthemf" ([impeach](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/impeach?s=t) the [motherfucker](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/motherfucker)). I'm reading an [article](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/etats-unis/201901/04/01-5210006-une-representante-democrate-propose-de-destituer-trump-le-qualifie-de-fils-de-pute.php) in French where this has been translated into *[destituons](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impeachment) le FDP* (*[fils](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fils/1) de pute* i.e. [son of a bitch](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/pute/64454?q=fils%20de%20pute#881970)). Yet *Larousse online* has [*enculé*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/motherfucker/596227) for motherfucker. I don't know if it means anything but I remember a [quote](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16105) from a movie which contains highly idiomatic French (from France) cursing and it has *enculé* (*de ta mère*; imho *of your* mother) and not *fils de pute* in it (*Nom de dieu de putain de bordel de merde de saloperie de connard d’enculé de ta mère*).

- Do *fils de pute* and *enculé* have the same meaning here; is either *enculé* or *fils de pute* a minced form for the other; do you see any reason for choosing *fils the pute* instead of *enculé* here?
- Incidentally is *enculé* generally construed as *enculé de ta mère*?

---

Même en n'ayant aucun compte sur un tel réseau... j'ai pris connaissance d'un [mot-clic](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26506610) qui contient un terme vulgaire argotique « impeachthemf » (*[impeach](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/impeach?s=t) the [motherfucker](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/motherfucker)*). Je lis un [article](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/etats-unis/201901/04/01-5210006-une-representante-democrate-propose-de-destituer-trump-le-qualifie-de-fils-de-pute.php)  en français où l'on a traduit ceci par « [destituons](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impeachment) le FDP » (*[fils](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fils/1) de pute*). Mais Larousse en ligne donne plutôt [*enculé*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/motherfucker/596227) pour *motherfucker*. Je ne sais pas si c'est significatif mais je me souviens d'une [citation](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16105) de film contenant une ribambelle de jurons particulièrement typiques en français (de France) et où l'on a *enculé* (*de ta mère*) mais pas *fils de pute* (*Nom de dieu de putain de bordel de merde de saloperie de connard d’enculé de ta mère*).

- Est-ce que *fils de pute* et *enculé* ont le même sens ici ; l'un de ces termes constitue-t-il une atténuation, un euphémisme de l'autre ; pourquoi aurait-on choisi le premier plutôt que le second ici ?
- Accessoirement, comprend-on généralement *enculé* comme signifiant *enculé
  de ta mère* ?

Comment: J'ajouterais que je suis pas super d'accord avec leur traduction, "*le fdp* n'est pas du tout idiomatique en français. *Destituons ce fdp* est bien plus proche de ce qu'on dirait en France. Après, c'est peut-être plus courant au Québec.

Comment: Concernant *fdp*, je trouve que *fils de pute* est bien plus fort en français que *motherfucker* en anglais. J'aurais plutôt choisi "*enfoiré*", qui lui-même est moins fort qu' "*enculé*". Il y avait eu un [autre évènement](https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2017/sep/22/donald-trump-nfl-national-anthem-protests) ou Trump avait utilisé *that son of a bitch* et à mon sens, traduire par "*ce fils de pute*" est bien trop fort, même si je ne trouve pas d'alternative plus proches.

Comment: C'est difficile de traduire les insultes parce que ce n'est pas parce qu'elle partagent le sens qu'elles ont la même "force" ou la même vulgarité. Les traductions des journalistes ne sont pas forcément les plus précises.

Comment: Que voulez-vous dire pas "EDC" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Est-ce que fils de pute et enculé ont le même sens ici ?

Leur sens littéral importe peu. Ce sont toutes deux des insultes crues et violentes.

> L'un de ces termes constitue-t-il une atténuation, un euphémisme de l'autre ;

Non.

> Pourquoi aurait-on choisi le premier plutôt que le second ici ?

Parce que, comme *motherfucker* avec **mf** et contrairement au second, le premier dispose d'une abréviation connue très facilement identifiable **fdp**. Cette abréviation atténue aussi la grossièreté de l'expression. Une autre abréviation connue et dans le même esprit que *mf* est **ntm**<sup>1</sup>. Elle est cependant probablement trop associée au [groupe de rap de même nom](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supr%C3%AAme_NTM).

> Accessoirement, comprend-on généralement enculé comme signifiant enculé de ta mère ?

Pas spécialement. *De ta mère* sert ici à intensifier l'insulte, comme aurait pu le faire aussi *de ta race* ou *de tes morts*. Ces suffixes « poétiques » certainement créés sous l'influence de l'arabe, en particulier *[nardinamouk](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/nardinamouk)* (maudite soit la religion de ta mère) sont arrivées en français d'abord via les Français d'Afrique du nord (Pieds-noirs), puis par les populations immigrées provenant du Maghreb. NTM vient d'ailleurs aussi probablement de l'arabe : *nicoumouk*.

<sub><sup>1</sup></sub> <sub>Abréviation de **n**ique **t**a **m**ère</sub>

Comment: Merci ! Je n'aurais jamais imaginé cette contribution pour les suffixes poétiques, je vais me coucher moins niaiseux à soir !

Comment: Je suis d'accord que le sens littéral n'a aucune importance. L'acceptabilité dans un contexte politique par contre a son importance, et je trouve que l'acceptabilité de « fils de pute » ou « enculé » ne correspond pas à celle de « motherfucker » *comme il est employé aux US*. Si j'avais à choisir une insulte employée dans des contextes similaires je dirais plutôt « connard ».

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez La morphologie de l'abréviation semble avoir été déterminante dans le choix. Je trouve aussi qu'on (Larousse en ligne par exemple) analyse trop la sémantique des composants du mot. Ce n'est pas le sujet mais il n'y a probablement aucune différence de sens entre _fucker_ et _motherfucker_. Il aurait fallu que je développe ça du côté de ELU/ELL mais c'est presque impossible de poser des questions comme celle-là là-bas, mon expérience c'est qu'on tolère plutôt mal qu'un apprenant s'intéresse à ça. Merci !

Comment: Je ne sais pas si c'est clairement ce que tu as dit, mais à mon sens *fdp* est clairement une atténuation de *fils de pute*.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Je parlais plutôt de la facilité avec laquelle l'abréviation est identifiée mais l'atténuation de la grossièreté est aussi réelle, je l'ai ajouté. Merci.

Comment: Petite remarque : « éponyme » (« qui donne son nom à quelque chose ») est mal employé ici. Le groupe de rap n'a donné son nom à rien, l’abréviation existait avant.

Comment: @Blackhole Damn, un [anglicisme](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eponymous)...

Answer (score 1):

1. Oui, les deux sont également méchants, sans fondation réelle quant à la condition de la personne insultée.
2. Non, cela doit être très rare en comparaison avec « putain de ta mère » qui est un terme standard, mais typique seulement de la population arabe ou de souche partiellement arabe.