# « Je suis un beau torvis/tord-vis » ?

Tags: québec, paroles-de-chanson

Dans la chanson [folklorique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chasse-galerie) québécoise [*Martin de la chasse-galerie*](https://youtu.be/efpdOA4y5IE) (composition Michel Rivard, inspiré d'un conte au recueil d'[Honoré Beaugrand](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honor%C3%A9_Beaugrand), interprétation La Bottine souriante, *La Mistrine*, 1994), on entend deux fois « *je suis un beau torvis, Martin d'la chasse-galerie* » :

> C'est moé l'plus jeune des dix, dans ce canot maudit 
>  Volant par
>   maléfice, au-dessus de vos vies
>  Épargnez vos prières, mes
>   parents, mes amis
>  *Je suis un beau torvis, Martin d'la
>   chasse-galerie*

Ailleurs on retranscrit *tord-vis* (je n'ai pas le livret original avec paroles). La construction avec le verbe être suivie de *en beau + sacre* n'est pas inhabituelle pour signifier la [colère](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacre_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Calvaire) (par ex., *je suis en beau torvis* : on comprendrait possiblement une variante [adoucie](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14388) de *torieu*). De plus, *torvis* ressemble au latin *torvus*, qui a éventuellement produit [*torve*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/torve) en français pour le *regard oblique, malveillant*, et par extension pour la personne comme telle (*TLFi* ; voir à la source aussi [*torvus*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/254187) au *FEW*, pour *fâché*, *mécontent*, et l'hapax legomenon *torvain* en ancien français pour *louche*). Or ici ce n'est pas introduit par *en* (la manière) mais bien *un*, et le contexte autorise peu, je crois, que le narrateur (Martin) s'autocritique (Satan/Lucifer, lui, s'en eût peut-être vanté..).

---

Peut-on en confirmer l'orthographe et qu'entend-on par *je suis un beau torvis/tord-vis* ici dans cette chanson ?

---

Comment: http://www.laparlure.com/terme/torvis/ (patois=juron)

Comment: J'ai indiqué patois=juron pour que les définitions soient compréhensibles. C'est le sens 2 qui s'impose: *caractère fourbe ou malvenu de quelqu'un ou quelque chose*.

Comment: @jlliagre Mais donc il dirait de lui-même (Martin) qu'il est fourbe ?? Pourquoi ? Je ne comprends pas le sens. Ou finalement est-ce Lucifer qui parlerait ?

Comment: Avoir fait un pacte avec le diable justifie qu'il s'attribue ces qualificatifs, non ?

Comment: Pour l'orthographe, pas de doute, c'est bien [torvis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52Uop50wxPI)...

Comment: Je pensais à l'orthographe utilisée par [Marco et les Torvis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52Uop50wxPI) qui font une reprise de Martin de la chasse-galerie mais en fouinant, j'ai aussi trouvé une autre orthographe amusante : [tord-vice](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Le_Parler_populaire_des_Canadiens_fran%C3%A7ais/T)...

Comment: @GAMPUB Amusant, difficile de voir si toutes les graphies représentent la même chose, mais avec cette orthographe j'y aurais vu une référence au baiser, vu le vice... donc on oscille entre le maudit/damné et le fourbe/vicieux. Au final, avec ou sans sémantique, p.-ê. un truc fonctionnel vu le juron, quelqu'un dans un état intense de qqc. selon le contexte de l'histoire, l'interdit, etc. Ne pas hésiter à faire une réponse, même partielle, avec ces éléments qu'on présente. Merci !

Answer (score 2):

Je n'ai pas trouvé l'étymologie de *torvis*, mais apparenter ce mot avec torve est plausible.

Le dictionnaire collaboratif [La parlure](http://www.laparlure.com/terme/torvis/) donne comme l'une des acceptions de *torvis* :

- caractère fourbe ou malvenu de quelqu'un ou quelque chose

Pactiser avec le diable est bien quelque chose de malvenu et «tordu», Martin demande à ses amis et parents de ne pas prier pour lui car c'est inutile et vain.