# Quel écrivain a le plus contribué au lexique de mots encore en usage aujourd'hui ?

Tags: histoire, littérature, néologismes, lexique

On sait que [Stendhal](https://books.google.com/books?id=kcftbdXPovIC&dq=Naples%20et%20Florence%20stendhal&pg=PA279#v=onepage&q=entrain&f=false) est responsable de la [création](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/entrain) du nom *entrain* (1817 ; mais on [ne sait](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/etre-entrain-de) toujours pas de quoi il en procède...). [Rimbaud](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2574) a composé une ribambelle d'interjections dont [*saperlipopette*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/saperlipopette). On peut trouver un article intéressant d'il y a 15 ans ([l'express](http://www.lexpress.fr/culture/livre/ecrivains-quels-mots-avez-vous-inventes_801863.html), « Écrivains, quels mots avez-vous inventés ? ») au sujet de diverses contributions d'écrivains au lexique, qui recense par exemple le *flûtiau bourru*, et le [*tube*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_(musique)) (pour la chanson à succès) nous dit-on, de Boris Vian, entre autres... Par ailleurs on trouve des [listes](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie:N%C3%A9ologismes_en_fran%C3%A7ais) de [néologismes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A9ologisme). Au final on en sait très peu.

---

- Quel écrivain a le plus contribué de mots au lexique de la langue française qui sont **encore en usage** aujourd'hui ; peut-on spécifier ?
- Quel auteur a inventé **le plus** de mots ou eu recours au néologisme le plus souvent dans son œuvre ; a-t-on un ordre de grandeur ; quelle(s) nuance(s) s'impose(nt) ?

Comment: Faudrait chercher le premier emploi de tous les mots plus récents que, disons… 100 ans… Parce qu’à mon avis c’est plutôt partagé. C’est un projet abracadabrantesque !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

François Rabelais est à ma connaissance l'un des plus grands forgeurs de mots de la langue française : cela est sans doute dû tant à sa personnalité créative qu'à la période, la Renaissance où la langue française moderne s'impose.
Qu'on en juge : parmi des centaines de mots qu'il a inventés, un grand nombre est resté vivant : célèbre, frugal, patriotique, bénéfique, génie, automate, gymnaste, indigène, horaire, quintessence ou anicroche. 
Il faut aussi citer les mots dérivés de ses personnages (gargantuesque, pantagruélique) et des expressions courantes : les moutons de Panurge, une guerre picrocholine, la dive bouteille ou la substantifique moelle...
C'est tellement pour un seul homme que certains parlent de la langue de Rabelais plus que de celle de Molière.

Comment: San-Antonio fut un peu dans la même veine, inventant sans relâche. Le répertoire français s'étant vastement enrichi entre Rabelais et San-Antonio, l'impact de ce dernier est sans doute moins frappant. Il a quand même mérité un dictionnaire pour lui seul... _(« J'ai fait
ma carrière avec un vocabulaire de 300 mots. Tous les autres, je les ai inventés. »_ –Frédéric Dard, alias San-Antonio).  À mettre aussi au dossier de Rabelais: l'art de la contrepèterie (qu'il nomma _antistrophe_, mais sa terminologie tomba éventuellement en désuétude).